# TeamCity REST API - List builds based on build parameters

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I've added a configuration parameter to a build configuration on a team city instance called "client".

This parameter is supplied every build, and can be viewed under the header User Defined Parameters and Actual Parameters on Agent in the parameters tab for a given a build (along with all the other parameters e.g. build.number, teamcity.project.id etc).

I can access this parameter for a build with -

```
server:port/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:xxx/resulting-properties/client
```

Let's say I went to get all builds where the client is Google. I have the build configuration id if that helps any.

I've searched high and low in the documentation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following request:

```
http://teamcity/app/rest/builds/?locator=property:(name:<name>,value:<value>),lookupLimit:1000
```

The search will be restricted by the 1000 most recent builds as otherwise the request can be quite slow and loading for the server.

Comment: mydomain.com/app/rest/builds?locator=count:100,property:(name:myParameter,value:myParameterValue)